# Вывести строки в которых нет столбца с nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, nan

Мне нужно вывести все строки в которых столбец Age не равен nan

```
p = pd.read_csv('output.csv', sep=';', encoding='Windows-1251')
word = 'nan' 
for line in p.Age:
    if word not in line:
        print(line)
```

но при попытке выполнения данного кода выдаёт ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/py.py", line 22, in <module>
    if word not in line:
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте просто так, «пандасонично», чтобы выбрать вами требуемы строки таблицы:

```
p[p.Age.notna()]
```

(и для вывода используйте то же самое выражение в функции `print()`).

---

*Объяснение:*

`p.Age` *серия чисел* (столбец), значит в вашей команде

```
for line in p.Age:
```

будет в переменной `line` **не** строка таблицы `p`, а число (типа `float`), как вам сообщает текст ошибки. Потому вы не можете сделать `if word not in line:`.

Comment: попробовал что то вроде `for line in p.Age.notna():
    print(line)` Но выводит лишь False и True попробовал `for line in p[p.Age.notna()]:
    print(line)` выводит лишь заголовки, а как мне вывести сами строки?

Comment: Вы пробуете то, что я вам не советовал. Просто `print(p[p.Age.notna()])`. Ни какой цикл `for`. Применение циклов в pandas всегда сомнительно.

Answer (score 3):

Кроме способа, указанного @MarianD, можно воспользоваться особым свойством `NaN`:

```
In [23]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[23]: False
```

Т.е. `NaN` не равен самому себе. Это даёт нам возможность воспользоваться удобным методом [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
print(p.query("Age == Age"))
```

выведет все строки для которых `Age == Age` - т.е. только те для которых `Age != NaN`

---

**NOTE:** решение от @MarianD является более предпочтительным, потому что оно более явно указывает на намерения автора кода. Решение с использованием метода `df.query()` удобно использовать когда мы фильтруем фрейм сразу по многим критериям.

Comment: Просили неравные, так что наоборот надо `==`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, исправил